# Cannot disable the textboxes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I could enable the textboxes as I click on the radio button using jquery. But I am not getting as to how to disable them if radio button is changed.

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2LCnC/

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class="jsRadioMasterSlaveContainer">
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radioMultiSelectCheckbox" class="jsRadioMaster" value=""> Upto N random selection count
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 3px;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Count" id="" style="width:80px" class="jsRadioSlave" disabled/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="jsRadioMasterSlaveContainer">
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radioMultiSelectCheckbox" id="" value="" class="jsRadioMaster"> Fixed selection count
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 3px;">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Count" id="" style="width:80px" class="jsRadioSlave" disabled/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="jsRadioMasterSlaveContainer">
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radioMultiSelectCheckbox" id="" class="jsRadioMaster"> Fixed index selection count
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 3px;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Count" id="" style="width:80px" class="jsRadioSlave" disabled/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(".jsRadioMaster").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    HandleMasterRadioChange($(this));
  });
});
function HandleMasterRadioChange(masterRadio) {
      $(masterRadio).closest(".jsRadioMasterSlaveContainer").find(".jsRadioSlave").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", !$(masterRadio).is(':checked'));
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prop(propertyName, function)` and return boolen based on radio in same row

```
$(".jsRadioMaster").change(function() {
   $('.jsRadioSlave').prop('disabled',function(){
      return !$(this).closest('tr').find('.jsRadioMaster').prop('checked')
   })
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2LCnC/750/)**</kbd>